# Making a number line to display one point in Java, getWidth() and getHeight() are not calibrating the position correctly

Tags: java, swing

So I want to make a number line class that I can use to display single points along a single axis, but I want it to respond to the size of the container it's in at the moment and to change its size relative to that. Unfortunately, I'm unable to use getWidth() and getHeight() correctly to get the number line I want. This is the code I have written so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class NumberLine extends JPanel {
    private int value;
    private Color green1 = new Color(32, 77, 2);

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    int maxXValue = getWidth();
    int maxYValue = getHeight();
    Line2D.Float xline = new Line2D.Float((float) maxXValue/6, (float) maxYValue/2, (float) maxXValue * (5/6), (float) maxYValue/2);
    Line2D.Float yline = new Line2D.Float( (float) maxXValue/ 2, (float) maxYValue * (9/20), (float) maxXValue/2, (float) maxYValue *(11/20));
    g2.draw(xline);
    g2.draw(yline);
    Ellipse2D.Float cir = new Ellipse2D.Float((float) (maxXValue/10 + (8 * value/1000) * (maxXValue)), (float) (maxYValue/2), 10F, 10F );
    g2.setColor(green1);
    g2.fill(cir);
}


public NumberLine(int val0) {
    value = val0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(150,100);
    NumberLine num = new NumberLine(5);
    frame.setContentPane(num);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Ideally, I would like something such that if I were to do

```
NumberLine num = new NumberLine(5);
```

I would get something that looks like:

[image: -*------------------]

Instead, I'm getting:

[image: Output from the code I have written]

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is one of basic geometry. If you're trying to center the circle within the line, then you need to subtract half its width and height from its location. That's it:

```
Ellipse2D.Float cir = new Ellipse2D.Float(
        (float) (maxXValue / 10 + (8 * value / 1000) * (maxXValue)) - 5,
        (float) (maxYValue / 2) - 5, 10F, 10F);
```

Also you're doing int division and that is returning 0 values where you don't want them. Change

```
Line2D.Float yline = new Line2D.Float((float) maxXValue / 2, (float) maxYValue * (9 / 20),
        (float) maxXValue / 2, (float) maxYValue * (11 / 20));
```

to

```
Line2D.Float yline = new Line2D.Float((float) maxXValue / 2, (float) maxYValue * (9f / 20f),
        (float) maxXValue / 2f, (float) maxYValue * (11f / 20f));
```

Unrelated issues:

- Don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method:

  ```
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g); // !! don't forget this!
  ```
- And avoid "magic" numbers in your program as they make debugging a bear.
- Use RenderingHints to smooth out your Graphics2D drawing:

  ```
  // rendering hints to smooth out your drawing
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  ```
- Start your Swing GUI on the EDT:

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  ```

For example, something like:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public @SuppressWarnings("serial")
class NumberLine3 extends JPanel {
    private static final double X_GAP = 1.0 / 20.0;
    private static final double MAJOR_TIC_HT = 0.4;
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 50;
    private static final Stroke MAIN_STROKE = new BasicStroke(5f);
    private static final Stroke MAJOR_TIC_STOKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
    private static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 20;
    private static final Color VALUE_COLOR = new Color(32, 230, 2);
    private int maxX;
    private int majorTickCount;
    private int minorTicksPerMajor;
    private double value;

    public NumberLine3(int maxX, int majorTickCount, int minorTicksPerMajor, double value) {
        this.maxX = maxX;
        this.majorTickCount = majorTickCount;
        this.minorTicksPerMajor = minorTicksPerMajor;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // rendering hints to smooth out your drawing
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Graphics2D g2b = (Graphics2D) g2.create(); // so we can change stroke without problems
        g2b.setStroke(MAIN_STROKE);
        int x1 = (int) xValueToScreen(-maxX);
        int y1 = getHeight() / 2;
        int x2 = (int) xValueToScreen(maxX);
        int y2 = y1;
        g2b.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g2b.setStroke(MAJOR_TIC_STOKE);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * majorTickCount; i++) {
            double xVal = ((double) i * maxX) / majorTickCount - maxX;
            x1 = (int) xValueToScreen(xVal);
            x2 = x1;
            double dY1 = getHeight() * (1 - MAJOR_TIC_HT) / 2.0;
            if (i == majorTickCount) {
                dY1 = 0.5 * dY1;
            }
            double dY2 = getHeight() - dY1;
            g2b.drawLine(x1, (int) dY1, x2, (int) dY2);
        }
        g2b.dispose();

        g2.setColor(VALUE_COLOR);
        x1 = (int) (xValueToScreen(value) - CIRCLE_WIDTH / 2.0);
        y1 = (int) (getHeight() - CIRCLE_WIDTH) / 2;
        g2.fillOval(x1, y1, CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_WIDTH);
    }

    private double xValueToScreen(double xValue) {
        double gap = getWidth() * X_GAP;
        double scale = (double) (getWidth() - 2 * gap) / (2 * maxX);
        return (xValue + maxX) * scale + gap;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getMaxX() {
        return maxX;
    }

    public int getMajorTickCount() {
        return majorTickCount;
    }

    public int getMinorTicksPerMajor() {
        return minorTicksPerMajor;
    }
}
```

Which can be tested with:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NumberLine3Test extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_X = 40;
    private static final int MAJOR_TICS = 4;
    private static final int MINOR_TICS = 5;
    private double value = 0.0;
    private NumberLine3 numberLine3 = new NumberLine3(MAX_X, MAJOR_TICS, MINOR_TICS, value);
    private JSlider slider = new JSlider(-MAX_X, MAX_X, 0);

    public NumberLine3Test() {
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.addChangeListener(ce -> {
            value = slider.getValue();
            numberLine3.setValue(value);
        });

        JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        sliderPanel.add(slider);
        int ebGap = 40;
        sliderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(numberLine3, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(sliderPanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        NumberLine3Test mainPanel = new NumberLine3Test();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NumberLine3");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is not really the position of the circle, it's the position of the lines. I would like a horizontal line that is in the centre not to the left as it is right now, and the vertical line that I have drawn is not even on screen. I have a couple of questions about your other points as well, what is an EDT? And, what are magic numbers? Although don't worry so much about the magic numbers, it sounds like the kind of thing I can easily search.

Comment: @JenniferHL3: ah, my bad. Please show a better ASCII image or *real* image of just what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JenniferHL3: EDT = Event Dispatch Thread. The main Swing thread that is responsible for key Swing actions including drawing and interacting with the user. See: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more on this.

Comment: @JenniferHL3: you're doing int division which will return 0 if the bottom denominator is greater than the numerator. Do double or float division instead.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added a new image of what I would like the program to produce in the original question. Ideally that axis would be centred in the JFrame.

Comment: @JenniferHL3: OK, well with the correction of int division, you should be able to get things running now, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it!